# Should all resistances in a RC filter be regarded?

Tags: resistors, low-pass

[image: Photo of a RC filter circuit]

I am trying to build a wah pedal and need to use the rc low pass filter. I know that this is supposed to be very easy to understand, but I'm having difficulities.

The thing is, when I connect the resistor and capacitor in parallels, it is supposed to choose between the grounded capacitor and resistor according to their resistance values.

This however confuses me as it is actually supposed to choose from the resistances in between its whole way to the ground. I want to know if the resistances outside of the RC filter should be regarded or not.

I would not like to post this here but what I have found on the internet about this was very ambiguous.

By the way the type of fİlter I want to build is a resistor on the straight wire and a grounded capacitor branching after the resistance

Comment: To build a wah wah pedal requires a band pass filter and not a simple RC low pass filter.

Comment: Thank you, but could you also answer the technical part of the question?

Comment: By the way I will be monitoring a transistor connected to a microcontroller, so it will be dynamic

Comment: I could but given your desire to build a wah wah pedal, it seems to be kind of missing the point. Why don't you modify your question and provide a link to an internet page that confuses you so that folk can address your specific tech difficulties. Lose the wah pedal reference too. Simplify!

Comment: Provide a schematic.

Comment: updated the question!

Comment: Your circuit does nothing so, let me explain, drop the wah wah talk because its not about wah stuff and show a proper circuit and explain your expectations. Link to a site that has confused you or drop that from your question. It seems that you need to learn how to ask a proper questions   I am trying to help but you are not listening.

Comment: I have simplified the question into the schematic that I have posted, just as you have asked, the only thing that I didn't do was to update the question to say that it was not a wah pedal at the end. I thought it was pretty obvious but ok.

Comment: http://www.geofex.com/article_folders/wahpedl/wahped.htm

Comment: it was the second image that had confused me. Using a single parameter(the wah resistor) to determine the whole bandpass would be very absurd as the amps have very different impedances. The capacitors would not be as effective in one amp as they are in the other, as the rc filter formula indicates. This is, if what I asked in the question was in fact right. What put me into a dillema however, were websites circling the capacitor and the resistor right next to it and puting their values into equations, disregarding the other resistant components.

Comment: @poyraz04: where is the input, where is the output???

Answer (score 1):

The time constant of the RC in your sketch is C*(R1+R2).

However, it will only do any low pass filtering with that time constant if you either ...

a) drive it at the circle with a current source, or

b) separate R2 from ground, and drive R2 with a voltage source with respect to ground

If you drive it at the circle with a series resistor, you will need to take into account the parallel combination of that with R1+R2 as well.